# How to tackle this SQL exercise?

Tags: sql

> table_cars : id, brand, type, license
>
> table_distances : id_car, date, distance
>
> table_equipments : id, name, description
>
> table_car_equipments : id_car, id_equipment
>
> Write the following queries:
>
> - Show all cars that have equipment "fire extinguisher" and have been    driving yesterday
> - Show all brands with no equipments
> - Show total distance driven by car "AB-2223-10" in the last month
> - Show average distance per day driven by cars from Paris

I am new in SQL.

I tried this:

```
select table_cars.id 
from table_cars, table_equipments 
where table_equipments.id = table_cars.id 
and table_equipments.name LIKE 'fire extinguisher';
```

Though I am confused that in table table_cars(id) and table_distances(id_car). are not the same. And I am stuck here.

Comment: You should try doing your homework first.

Comment: If you had paid attention in class you'd see this is the easiest of all queries. Study hard, it gets worse.

Comment: Try writing it yourself first.  Google is your friend.  Come back and repost this afterwards if you're stuck and can show us what you've done and what you can't get to work.

Comment: Well to be honest, i tried to:
select table_cars.id
 from table_cars, table_equipments
 where table_equipments.id = table_cars.id
       and table_equipments.name LIKE 'fire extinguisher';

Though I am confused that in table table_cars(id) and table_distances(id_car). are not the same. And I am stuck here)

Comment: Your query mentions table_equipments and your text mentions table_distances.  Something is missing.  By the way, does your query return any records?

Comment: Don't use comma joins.

Comment: Dont give it to him,let the kid learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your where clause, you try to use a column that does not exist `table_equipments.id`.

The key for the `table_cars` is `id`, when this is referred to in the `table_equipments`, it is called the `id_car` to indicate this is the id of a car (and not some other entity) and that it will match the `id` value of a single record in the `table_cars` table.

This is called a 'foreign key': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key